# What causes a large exe to load slowly (65,536 bytes at time according to Procmon)?

Tags: docker, performance, procmon

We are running Docker on a VMware host running Windows 10.

[image: Docker exe loading 65k bytes each read]

Based on the first comment, I wonder if the issue isn't specifically the read portion, but maybe there is something happening at the end of the load that is preventing this exe from being cached in memory.

[image]

Comment: That seems perfectly normal for memory-mapped files (which includes executables) being paged in when necessary

Comment: @BenVoigt Interesting. I just tried running the command again before running procmon and I still see that sequence happening twice within the same "docker ps" call.  I don't see the same thing happening in an Azure VM.  Is there some Windows setting to prevent caching memory-mapped files?